Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply') error in leadfoot
Preq:
I'm trying to access an existing chrome session and send leadfoot command but failing at the last step of sending leadfoot command to the chrome browser.
Please suggest if any changes to be done.
Below is my code snippet:
requirejs(['leadfoot/Server', 'leadfoot/Command'], function (Server, Command) {
const webDriverUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:16978/wd/hub';

async function run() {
    try {
      
        const server = new Server(webDriverUrl);
        console.log('Server instance created:', server);

        const sessions = await server.getSessions();
        console.log('Connected to existing sessions:', sessions);

        const sessionId = sessions[0].id; 
        console.log('Connected to existing sessionId:', sessionId);
      
       let sessionCommand;
        try {               
            sessionCommand = new Command({ sessionId: sessionId });
            console.log('Command instance created:', sessionCommand);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error creating Command instance:', error.message);
            throw error;
        }

        // Perform the action
        console.log('Finding username field and typing...');
        try {
            const element = await sessionCommand.findByCssSelector('input[name="username"]');
            await element.type('yourUsername'); //Failing at this step
            console.log('Typed in username field');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error during command execution:', error.message);
            throw error;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error.message);
    }
}
run();
});

Output traces as below:
Server instance created: Server { url: 'http://127.0.0.1:16978/wd/hub/', requestOptions: {} }
Fetching sessions...
Connected to existing sessions: [
  {
    capabilities: {
     ...
    },
    id: '340f29216c6788c668cf30ac08771e70'
  }
]
Connected to existing sessionId: 340f29216c6788c668cf30ac08771e70
Command instance created: Command {
  _session: { sessionId: '340f29216c6788c668cf30ac08771e70' },
  _promise: Promise {
    cancel: [Function (anonymous)],
    then: [Function (anonymous)]
  }
}
Finding username field and typing...
Error during command execution: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')

